# Yii 2: (recursive) tree searchModel

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i'm searching an idea to implement in Yii 2 a searchModel that pulls data from mysql like a Tree.

An example: i have a tree structure with users and all user have (one or more) contract.  Now i would to get from my db all contracts signed by "user_id" and all others contract signed by every son (and son of son..ecc..) of "user_id".

I know how i can read all "user_id"'son (i use a recursive function in a view), but after...?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like [nested sets](https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets) for me.

Comment: @chris--- mmm i don't like so much this solution :/

Comment: Ok. I've solved the problem :)
In the next days i will put few lines of code to show how i solved this.